# I cannot install Animation Nodes add-on

Tags: animation, node-editor, add-on, animation-nodes, installation

I am trying to install an Animation Nodes add-on to Blender 2.8. I tired  GraphicAll and Github respectively. The system is rejecting and error message said that I have multiple versions of animation add-on already installed.

I never download this version of add-on before, most of my add-on are default add-on by Blender. After couple of initial rejections, I went through all add-on and removed most animation add-on I didn't use.

I am still having same issue installing this add-on. I have reset/refresh computer couple of times, cleared memory though it doesn't need much. I have attached screen shot if anyone else can see issue I cannot.

[image]

Comment: Is this about download or installing addons? Download issues are off topic here and have nothing to do with Blender. If it is an install issue please make it clear in your question. Please edit you question and add more details describing your workflow and what precise steps you took.

Comment: You can read the common problems while installing this add-on there : https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/issues/1240

Comment: Thank you for the link, i have followed and disabled all animation nodes prior to installation. I only have camera and nuke animation. It's still showing same issue.